# Can't pass data from asp.net webforms to client side using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am trying to pass some data to client side using ajax, but can't do it succesfully. I get error in browser failed to load resource. I checked jQuery is loaded correctly.

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetGraphData()
    {

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int[,] datar = new int[,] { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 13 }, { 4, 17 } };
            // create columns
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                // create a DataRow using .NewRow()
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                // iterate over all columns to fill the row
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = datar[j, i];
                }

                // add the current row to the DataTable
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            string JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            return JsonString;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

This is my c# code. It is placed in controller named HomeController.cs.

Here is my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/GetGraphData',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Data is here");
        console.log(result);
        
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Data isnt here");
    }
});

})
```

I am trying to pass data from asp.net webforms and i am using .net framework 4.5. I am trying just to send data for now and i will worry about other thins when i successfuly send it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get a huge award for introductiong the term and concept and name "controler" when you are using web forms. (getting paid to confuse people here???).

So, in web forms, you doing a ajax call, and that requires you to setup a web method to be called as ajax.

You can either:

Create a new seperate web page (asmx page), OR YOU can add some web methods to your existing web form page.

So, markup will be this:

```
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Web Service Call" 
            OnClientClick="myjava();return false"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="245px" Width="704px"
            ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine"
            ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
    </div>

    <script>
        function myjava() {
            // call web method in page
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxTest1.aspx/GetGraphData",
                data:{},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (myresult) {
                    // put result of method call into txtResult
                    // ajax data is ALWAYS ".d" - its a asp.net thing!!!
                    $('#TextBox2').val(myresult.d)

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

code behind on this same web form page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string GetGraphData()
    {
        int[,] datar = new int[,] { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 13 }, { 4, 17 } };
        return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datar);
    }
```

And we run, and get this:

[image]

Now, NOTE how I set the data type of that function to return a string.

I could return a serialized object - change "string" of the function to int[,] and we can return that object.

So, say this:

```
     [WebMethod()]
    public static int[,] GetGraphData()
    {
        int[,] datar = new int[,] { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 13 }, { 4, 17 } };
        return  datar;
    }
```

So, now that we set the type of the function, then return will AUTOMATIC serlize to the object type int[,]

At this point, then client side code could reverse the object back to a string.

eg this:

```
    $('#TextBox2').val(JSON.stringify(myresult.d))
```

And now we get this:

[image]

so result.d (d means data return) is the result.

but, if we remove the json.Stringify, then we have a js object.

eg this:

```
    $('#TextBox2').val(myresult.d[1,1])
```

And now this:

[image]

Also note:

the page method is public STATIC. This is because you calling webmethod. that means you don't have use of controls on the page, no post-back, and hence no class instance of the page object. You cant use viewstate either (but, you can use session).

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try this later. I am really new to this, I just started learning.

Comment: I now get System.InvalidOperationException, can you help me with that also? Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: The code as posted works. Try creating a new blank web form page. Drop in the above markup. You have to change the page name used AjaxTest1.aspx/GetGraphData to MyTestPage/TheWebMethodGoesHere, and it should work.  So, don't use a "/" in front, but just the name of your current web page. We assume the page has jQuery working.  Example code posted is for webforms, and not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

test it after adding this in your ajax property,

```
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/GetGraphData',                
        dataType: "json",
        ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: I still dont get anything. The problem is, my action method in controller is never called.

Comment: if you using a controller, then this is not  asp.net webforms, but sounds like this is a asp.net MVC project - there is  VAST difference between the two types of projects. So, is this asp.net webform project, or is this a MVC. And if it is MVC, the you not using web forms, and the above examples will not apply then.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    
    $.ajax({
    
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/GetGraphData',                
        dataType: "json",
        ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Data is here");
            console.log(result);
            
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Data isnt here");
        }
    });
    
    })
```

Comment: This doesn't work.